# SQL Array Search

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a group feature on my website that allows 1 user to put the userids of any of his or her friends into an invitedusers column. I need to do an SQL search to determine whether the logged-in user's ID has been stored in any invitedusers columns by his or her friends.
How can I do this with an sql search?

EX: My column is invitedusers, and inside that column is stored the following, (234,394,479)
When Userid 234 has logged in, I need to search to see whether any columns have userid 234 stored inside the invitedusers column.

```
SELECT userid, name... FROM mytable WHERE invitedusers = ?
```

*I looked at the SQL IN operator along with FIND_IN_SET but no help with either.*

Comment: I think you're looking for `LIKE`. As in, `SELECT userid, name... FROM mytable WHERE invitedusers LIKE '%234%'`

Comment: I'm afraid we cannot help you without table schema examples.

Comment: Why do people constantly struggle to find ways to bypass their bad database design rather than design cleanly normalized tables in the first place?

Comment: Presumably you're storing all of these invites and such in tables, so you'll need to do some kind of join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're really using `234,394,479` as value of one column (you at least should use `,234,394,479,` to be able to do `WHERE invited LIKE '%,234,%'` in your query) you should rebuild your user tables, remove field `invited_users` and create table like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE invited_users (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  owner_id INT, -- Who's input it is
  target_id INT, -- What's the target user
  PRIMARY KEY ( id),
  UNIQUE ( owner_id, target_id),
  -- Indexes (FOREIGN KEYs!) to users table
);
```

And than just select list of users who invited user 234 with query:

```sql
SELECT users.id, users.name
FROM invited_users
INNER JOIN users ON invited_users.owner_id = users.id
GROUP BY users.id
WHERE invited_users.target_id = 234
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this Vyktor. Definitely implementing it.

Answer (score 1):

You may not want to store a comma delimited list in a column, but since you are:

```
SELECT userid, name FROM mytable
WHERE invitedusers = '(' + '234' + ')' -- One and only one entry
OR invitedusers LIKE '(' + '234' + ',%' -- First entry
OR invitedusers LIKE '%,' + '234' + ',%' -- Middle entry
OR invitedusers LIKE '%,' + '234' + ')%' -- Last entry
```

I have modified based on EBarr's comment.  There are four cases to check for.  This assumes you are storing the data with a ( prefix and a ) suffix and separating everything with commas.

Here are some tests to prove that it works:

```
/* Tests */
INSERT INTO @mytable SELECT 11, 'a', '(234)' -- Should get returned
INSERT INTO @mytable SELECT 12, 'b', '(1234)'
INSERT INTO @mytable SELECT 13, 'c', '(92349)'
INSERT INTO @mytable SELECT 13, 'd', '(2345)'

INSERT INTO @mytable SELECT 21, 'a', '(234,567)' -- Should get returned
INSERT INTO @mytable SELECT 22, 'b', '(1234,567)'
INSERT INTO @mytable SELECT 23, 'c', '(92349,567)'
INSERT INTO @mytable SELECT 23, 'd', '(2345,567)'

INSERT INTO @mytable SELECT 31, 'a', '(567,234)' -- Should get returned
INSERT INTO @mytable SELECT 32, 'b', '(567,1234)'
INSERT INTO @mytable SELECT 33, 'c', '(567,92349)'
INSERT INTO @mytable SELECT 33, 'd', '(567,2345)'

INSERT INTO @mytable SELECT 41, 'a', '(123,234,789)' -- Should get returned
INSERT INTO @mytable SELECT 42, 'b', '(123,1234,789)'
INSERT INTO @mytable SELECT 43, 'c', '(123,92349,789)'
INSERT INTO @mytable SELECT 43, 'd', '(123,2345,789)'

SELECT userid, name FROM @mytable
WHERE invitedusers = '(' + '234' + ')' -- One and only one entry
OR invitedusers LIKE '(' + '234' + ',%' -- First entry
OR invitedusers LIKE '%,' + '234' + ',%' -- Middle entry
OR invitedusers LIKE '%,' + '234' + ')%' -- Last entry
```

Comment: You need to add the delimiter to your LIKE criteria.  As written you'll match entries for 234,  1234, 92349, and 2345

Comment: Hi Steven. What would be a better solution to a comma delimite list?

Comment: Create a child table that has a one to many relationship with your parent.  Then your query would become something like:


SELECT a.userid, a.name
  FROM mytable a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN mychildtable b
    ON a.userid = b.userid
   WHERE b.invitedusers = 234

Comment: Wow, thanks! This did it but it seems I have to re-design my structure.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
SELECT userid, name... FROM mytable WHERE FIND_IN_SET('234', invitedusers) !=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way but:

```
where concat(',',invitedusers,',') like '%,234,%'
```

So in your example `,234,` is inside `,234,394,479,`