# PHP Separate comma list with links

Tags: php, mysql, list, replace

I have a MySQL field called "tags" an example result. The single field has a list of text with comma separated values.

A real example:

`red, pants, shoes, heels, lookbook`

I want to somehow use find and replace or implode feature to print out this row as separate links.

My guess so far:

```
<?php
$tag=$row["tags"];
whilst (!$tag=="") { 
echo '<a href="/tags/$tag">$tag</a>, "';
}
?>
```

Comment: [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) will work. Then walk through the result using `foreach`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. split the comma separated list into an array using `explode()`
2. convert each element in the list to a link using `foreach`
3. convert the array to a comma separated list using `implode()`

example:

```
$tags = explode(", ", $row["tags"]);
foreach ($tags as &$tag) {
    $tag = "<a href=\"/tags/$tag\">$tag</a>";
}
echo implode(", ", $tags);
```

Another approach would be using `preg_replace`:

```
$row['tags'] = "banana, apple, peach, strawberry";
echo preg_replace( '#([^,\s]+)#is', 
       '<a href="/tags/$1">$1</a>', 
       $row['tags']);
```

Comment: This is nice, but the list will end in a comma: `1,2,3,4,`

Comment: So can I use a replace last on the new string?

Comment: you could also remove the last comma from the string, but i think the approach in my edited post is much better

Comment: @Vyktor serious, I meant using a reference in foreach (although what you say about changing the database structure is far better of course)

Comment: <3 references, when applied correctly. makes code more readable and wastes less memory and cpu cycles.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably take a look at this answer first [SQL Array Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200966/sql-array-search/9201135#9201135) (how to store such an information in the database). If you still want to use coma separated list, the best way is probably using [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```php
function generateLink( $tag){
    $tag = htmlspecialchars( trim( $tag));
    $str = "<a href=\"/tags/$tag\">$tag</a>";
}

$tags = explode( ',', $row['tags']);
$new_tags = array_map( 'generateLink', $tags);
echo implode( ', ', $new_tags);

// Of course you can chain it to:
echo implode( ', ', array_map( 'generateLink', explode( ',', $row['tags'])));
```

However if you use correct database design you should this `SELECT` (displaying one product):

```sql
SELECT tags.name
FROM tags_products
INNER JOIN tags ON tags_products.tag_id = tags.id
WHERE tags_products,product_id = ?
```

And with php:

```php
$q = $db->query( 'mentioned select');
$result = array();
while( $row = $q->fetch_assoc()){
    $result[] = genereateLink( $row['name']);
}
```

And in case of mass listing of product to increase performance use this select with [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```sql
SELECT products.id, products.name, GROUP_CONCAT(tags.name ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS tags
FROM products
LEFT JOIN tags_products ON tags_producsts.product_id = products.id
INNER JOIN tags ON tags_products.tag_id = tags.id
GROUP BY products.id
```

And apply the first mentioned code on `$row['tags']` :)

Comment: @Kaii if you have tutorial on how to design such a table I'll be glad to add it... I have troubles finding it in English.

Comment: Appreciate all comments - the reason why I went with this approach is I did not want another table called tags associated with products. So I made it in a single row. Thanks for all comments. Repped

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid when your database grows and/or you want to add features (like, say.. search by tag) you will run into performance problems with that approach. we warned you ;)